# Подключение к удалённому серверу нему через сокеты на Java

Tags: java

Я пытаюсь написать программу для связи между компьютерами на Java. Я использую IP своего компьютера, и на том и на другом устройстве, но подключиться не получается. Помогите пожалуйста

```java
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        //Я получил свой IP с консоли Windows
        //Я пробовал публичный IP, но кидает исключение: Cannot assign requested address: bind
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(""); //Здесь типа мой IP
        try(ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(90,50,address)){
            System.out.println(server.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
            writer.println("Hello, World!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

//Класс клиента на другом ПК
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try(Socket socket = new Socket()) {
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("",90));//Тут тот же IP
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: мало исходных данных. Начать стоило бы с технической возможности подключения. Оба компьютера в одной локальной сети? Прописанные порты открыты, файрволлы и роутер настроены на пропуск трафика от этих приложений по нужным портам? В чем выражается "не получается" - должна быть какая-то конкретная ошибка с конкретным текстом. Этим всем стоит дополнить вопрос.

Comment: Пишет, что невозможно запустить сервер на данном IP.

Answer (score 0):

Создание сервера:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(47000); //47000-порт
```

Создание клиента:

```
Socket client = new Socket("192.168.0.0", 47000); //192.168.0.0-ipv4
```

Всё это с отловом ошибок. Должно работать.

Comment: А я смогу подключиться к серверу с другого компьютера?

Comment: @user504062, если эти два компьютера будут в одной сети. Если вы собираетесь приобрести VPS, то сможете подключаться в любом месте, так как у них уже есть статический IP. У меня есть один сервер, так что спрашивайте. Не забудте про перенаправление портов с внешнего на внутренний(на VPS).

Comment: Т.е. подключены к одному Wi-Fi? Дело в том что, я пользуюсь раздачей мобильного интернета.

Comment: @user504062, да, это локальная сеть. Ip можно через код получать.

Comment: А как уточнить IP через код?